# How can I put condition in serverless.yml file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

I am using `serverless` framework to deploy api gateway. I don't want to apply VPC to every stage in serverless. Is there a way for me to add below configuration based on `stage` name?

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x

...

endpointType: PRIVATE
vpcEndpointIds:
    -  'Fn::ImportValue': 'api-gateway-endpoint'
resourcePolicy:
    - Effect: Deny
...
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may check the following answers: [Conditional serverless.yml based on stage?](https://forum.serverless.com/t/conditional-serverless-yml-based-on-stage/1763/5)

Therefore, you get something like:

```
resources:
    Conditions:
        IsProd:
          Fn::Equals:
            - ${opt:stage}
            - prod  

    Resources:
        SomeIAMRole:
            Type: AWS::IAM::Role
            Condition: IsProd
            Properties:
                etc
                etc
```

Answer (score 19):

There are a few ways to do conditional deployments in serverless.yml, some are more brittle than others and there are pros/cons to each but here is a list of methods I have collected:

### Variables to control conditionals

**NOTE:** We use a custom regex variable syntax to separate Serverless variables from cloudformation variable syntax. All of the following snippets use this modified syntax:

```yaml
provider:
  name: aws
  # Changes serverless variable to ${{}} double curly braces
  variableSyntax: "\\${{([ ~:a-zA-Z0-9._\\'\",\\-\\/\\(\\)]+?)}}"
```

##### [Serverless Custom Variables](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables/)

```yaml
custom:
  scheduleEnabled:
    dev: true
    stage: true
    prod: true

# Then In lambda function declaration
    events:
      - schedule:
          name: MyScheduleName
          description: SomeDescription
          rate: cron(0/5 * * * ? *)
          # Use custom variable and the serverless `stage` supplied 
          # via your deployment command to choose whether this feature is enabled
          enabled: ${self:custom.scheduleEnabled.${self:custom.stage}} 
          input: {"_keepwarm": true}
```

### Using Conditional Operations

##### Setting up CloudFormation Conditionals

```yaml
resources:
  - Conditions:
      # True if they are equal ==
      MyCondition: [!Equals ["${{env:SOMETHING}}","SOME_STRING"]]
      # True if they are not equal !=
      MyConditionTwo: !Not [!Equals ["${{env:SOMETHING_ELSE}}","SOME_OTHER_STRING"]]
      # Using a custom serverless variable
      IsProd: [!Equals ["${{self:provider.stage}}","prod"]]
```

##### Using Cloudformation Conditionals

If your conditional has two options, you can write it as:

```yaml
# If true choose X, if False choose Y
Source:
  Type: !If
    - MyCondition # Conditional Name
    - GITHUB # If condition is true
    - GITHUB_ENTERPRISE # if condition is false
```

If your conditional is something you want to toggle ON or OFF, you can write it as:

```yaml
# If True do nothing, If False choose X
MyCodebuildSetup:
  Type: "AWS::CodeBuild::Project"
  VpcConfig: !If
    - MyCondition # Condition Name
    - !Ref AWS::NoValue # If True, AWS will not attach a VPC Config
    - VpcId: <My_VPC_ID> # If False, Use this VPC Config
      Subnets:
        - <my_VPC_Subnet>
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - <my_VPC_security_group
```

### Weird Conditional Hacks (document usage well if you decide to implement them)

##### Conditionally deploying a large series of resources

Using Serverless to selectively deploy entire files of resources using strings set via environment variables.

```yaml
resources:
  - ${{file(some_dir/conditional_file_${{env:MY_CONDITION}}.yml)}}
```

This is also a way to toggle deployment of many resources via conditionals.

`conditional_file_A.yaml` can contain all the resources you toggle deployment of, while `conditional_file_B.yaml` can contain an empty Resources list (If you don't want a "file not found" warning from serverless:

```yaml
Resources:
```

##### Using Serverless Variables in buildspec.yml files or .json files that will be sent to cloudformation (parameter store files, etc)

If you want to conditionally modify a .json or .yml file that will be sent deployed as a value for some CloudFormation key (such as deploying a `.json` file for parameter store, or submitting `buildspec.yml` files for CodePipeline), you can't actually use ${} serverless syntax in these external files. This is because [serverless gets confused with it's own  method of calling Key/Values from external files](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables/#reference-properties-in-other-files).

In order to use Serverless Variables in these files, you can make them .txt extensions as long as the actual file is formatted as proper .json or .yml

```yaml
Source:
  Type: CODEPIPELINE
  # This file can't have any serverless variables in it
  BuildSpec: ${{file(my_buildspec_file.yml)}}
```

```yaml
Source:
  Type: CODEPIPELINE
  # This file CAN have serverless variables because it is 
  # interpreted by serverless as a .txt, the variables
  # are resolved and then it is sent to cloudformation as a string anyway
  BuildSpec: ${{file(my_buildspec_file_yaml_formatted.txt)}}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful. Just wanted to point out that the serverless.yml now needsa fallback for variable conditioned values, so `enabled: ${self:custom.scheduleEnabled.${self:custom.stage}}` becomes `enabled: ${self:custom.scheduleEnabled.${self:custom.stage}, false}`

Comment: This was super helpful and helped me achieve what I intended to. 

It would be final cherry on the top, if in the custom variables approach there is a way to centralise the expression `${self:custom.scheduleEnabled.${self:custom.stage}}`. So that in case the variable name update happens, that happens only in one place. Like a function or a Condition in AWS terms probably?

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, there is a `Serverless Plugin Ifelse`

Add the plugin:

```
plugins:  
  - serverless-plugin-ifelse
```

and then add your conditions:

```
custom:
.....
....

  serverlessIfElse:
    - If: '"${opt:stage}" == "production"'    
      Set:
        functions.helloWorld.cors: true
```

see more info [Serveless plugin if-else](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-plugin-ifelse)